# Are there no DNS entries for static pi-hole dhcp hostnames?

Tags: dns, dhcp, dhcp-server, pihole

A pi-hole instance is also acting as the DHCP server in my network. I assigned static IP addresses for some of my devices (eg. an octopi server with Hostname "octopi" and IP address "192.168.1.40"). The pi-hole domain name is set to "lan". But when trying to ping "octopi.lan" from my computer (where the pi-hole is set as it's DNS) the name cannot be resolved. Are additional configuration steps necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: I just found out that the DNS resolution seems to work on my iPhone, but not on my Windows 10 PC.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the problem went away without changing anything - just waiting some hours.